# What's new in SP1 for .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, .net-3.5

Is there an exact overview what has changed in the SP1 for .NET 3.5? New classes, methods, etc.

For example, I've noticed there is a new `WaitOne(TimeSpan)` and `WaitOne(int)` overloads in the `WaitHandle` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Low level comparison of SP1 assemblies vs .NET 3.5](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/08/13/net-3-5-sp1-changes-overview.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

[What's New in the .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP1 - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713697.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There's a good summary here. (Ignore the fact that it's talking about the beta version)

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/05/12/visual-studio-2008-and-net-framework-3-5-service-pack-1-beta.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**.NET Framework Client Profile** is a great feature , check all the features http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713697.aspx